# Int equivalent function in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using Mvc framework and i want to migrate vb code to c#. Right now i want to use **Int** function equivalent in c#.

Example:-

```
result.ReducedSeconds = (dblReducedAngle - (Int(dblReducedAngle)) * 60)
```

I want to get result in c#

Comment: Use the Convert.ToInt32 method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffdk7eyz(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try directly casting to an Int:

```
result.ReducedSeconds = (dblReducedAngle - ((int)dblReducedAngle) * 60)
```

Comment: Just remember that casting won't work if type string, for example.

Comment: Yes that is true. But the equivalent Int() method conversion in VB does not take a string input so we can assume safely that his variable dblReducedAngle is numeric.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know vb but if it simply converts variable to integer then you will use

```
Convert.ToInt32(dblReducedAngle)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is a string, you can use

```
var myIntNumber = int.Parse(numberAsString);
```

Be careful if the string is any combination of characters like "hello123" this will end in an exception, but any string like "20" will work fine (Take a look at **TryParse** to control this possible exception).

Otherwise you just make a casting (assuming the variable is numeric type).

```
(int)anyNumericVariable
```